# laravel views and routers undefined object

Tags: php, laravel

My routes:

```
Route::get("/home/{lang?}", function ($lang=null){

    App::setlocale($lang);
    return view('/home');

});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('/home','RadarController');
Route::resource('/welcome1','DriverController');
Route::post('/welcome1', 'DriverController@store');
```

In views I got:

```
 @foreach($radars2 as $radar)

            <tr>
                <td>{{$radar['id']}}</td>
```

mine index function

```
public function index()
{
    $radars2 = Radar::all();
    // return view('home', compact($radars2));
    return  view('home', ['radars2' => $radars2]);
}
```

So the thing is, when I add locale route I get Undefined variable: radars2 error.
Without locale route it works fine, so what problem it could be? Tried with compact and with array result the same, even tried adding that locale route in my resource controller route, still the same issue.

Comment: your `"/home/{lang?}"`  is new `route` so you need pass `HomeController@index` in that `route`

Answer (score 0):

In your locale route, you're trying to render view 'home', but you didn't pass any parameters in there

```
Route::get("/home/{lang?}", function ($lang = null) {
    App::setlocale($lang);
    return view('/home'); //problem is here
});
```

It should be something like:

```
Route::get("/home/{lang?}", function ($lang = null) {
    App::setlocale($lang);
    $radars2 = Radar::all();
    return view('/home', ['radars2' => $radars2]);
});
```